# Next.js page goes blank after a brief second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js14

So suddenly my next.js page just went blank, after a brief second, I didn't change anything, it just happened. I tried to restart my dev server and deleted the '.next' folder, nothing worked. At least I got some errors in the console. I guess the page is blank, because of some error server-side, but these errors couldn't help me. Btw my page is using "use client";

**EDIT:**
I found the error, it was not a Next.js error (who would thought), a mistake from my side, I imported a exported function, from a file, that imported some files, that not work client-side.

> It's also not a browser specific error, I tried Chrome and Edge, same results.

> Only on the '/login' page, I get the below errors, on my register or one time password verification page (both using "use client"), I get no errors, but all pages are blank.

> And in the network tab, I don't get any 404 errors.
> And I get the same errors in production (deployed to vercel).

Here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "bazcord",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "prisma generate && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.5.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@nextui-org/input": "^2.1.17",
    "@prisma/client": "5.10.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-hover-card": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-scroll-area": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.1.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.0.7",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.28.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "@uploadthing/react": "^6.3.4",
    "@upstash/redis": "^1.28.4",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "cmdk": "^1.0.0",
    "input-otp": "^1.2.3",
    "lucide-react": "^0.354.0",
    "next": "14.1.3",
    "next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.16",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "query-string": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.0",
    "react-markdown": "^9.0.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0",
    "rehype-external-links": "^3.0.0",
    "rehype-raw": "^7.0.0",
    "rehype-sanitize": "^6.0.0",
    "remark-gfm": "^4.0.0",
    "remark-math": "^6.0.0",
    "resend": "^3.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "uploadthing": "^6.5.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "zod": "^3.22.4",
    "zustand": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.10",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.11",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prisma": "^5.10.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Maybe you can help? Thanks.

Here is the full error:

```
react-server-dom-web…development.js:1183 
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')
    at new n (nodejs.mjs:1:222)
    at eval (redis.ts:3:15)
    at (app-pages-browser)/l…login/page.js:428:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:716:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:371:21)
    at eval (otp.ts:9:68)
    at (app-pages-browser)/l…login/page.js:417:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:716:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:371:21)
    at eval (page.tsx:22:67)
    at (app-pages-browser)/a…login/page.js:329:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:716:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:371:21)
    at requireModule (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:156:23)
    at initializeModuleChunk (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:1357:1)
    at parseModelString (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:1665:1)
    at Object.eval (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:2018:1)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseModel (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:2010:1)
    at initializeModelChunk (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:1325:1)
    at readChunk (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:1163:1)
    at reconcileChildFibersImpl (react-dom.development.js:9854:1)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:9912:1)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:15627:1)
    at replayFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:16236:1)
    at replaySuspendedUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:25695:1)
    at renderRootConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:25467:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24432:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:256:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:225:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:534:1)
app-index.js:33 
 The above error occurred in the <ServerRoot> component:

    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.3_re…-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:129:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.3_re…-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:145:11)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
react-dom.development.js:16472 
 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
    at updateHostRoot (react-dom.development.js:16472:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:18410:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:26791:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:25637:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:25353:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:25308:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:24525:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24470:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:256:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:225:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:534:1)
react-dom.development.js:26203 
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')
    at new n (nodejs.mjs:1:222)
    at eval (redis.ts:3:15)
    at (app-pages-browser)/l…login/page.js:428:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:716:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:371:21)
    at eval (otp.ts:9:68)
    at (app-pages-browser)/l…login/page.js:417:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:716:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:371:21)
    at eval (page.tsx:22:67)
    at (app-pages-browser)/a…login/page.js:329:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:716:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?v=1711538661176:371:21)
    at requireModule (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:156:23)
    at initializeModuleChunk (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:1357:1)
    at parseModelString (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:1665:1)
    at Object.eval (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:2018:1)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseModel (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:2010:1)
    at initializeModelChunk (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:1325:1)
    at readChunk (react-server-dom-web…velopment.js:1163:1)
    at reconcileChildFibersImpl (react-dom.development.js:9854:1)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:9912:1)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:15627:1)
    at replayFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:16236:1)
    at replaySuspendedUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:25695:1)
    at renderRootConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:25467:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24432:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:256:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:225:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:534:1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, it was not a Next.js error (who would thought), a mistake from my side, I imported a exported function, from a file, that imported some files, that not work client-side.